# The strange ways of IE7: divs with floats

Tags: html, css-float

I read few articles on float used with nested divs but I'm unsure as to where the real culprit is...

The following is the html I'm using ..It works everywhere but in IE7.

The fiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/7NynC/8/

Hope some html souls to make this life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE7 is sort of screwy in that respect. If you want your right-floated elements to stay on the same line, you'll need to place them higher in the markup, i.e. before the element to which it's supposed to appear adjacent. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NynC/10/))

Comment: Exactly @antisanity....i swapped the positions..and now the elements are living in peace and harmony....

Comment: @Premanshu This can become a real pain if you're doing this with things having a tabindex.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your problem is that the toolbar to the right is dropping down a line (I didn't check IE7). Just switch their position in the code (put the right-floated element first) and it should fix it.

Comment: exactly....but all my elements have the float property as right....and then i just placed the right floated before the others...and how may i thank you.....really strange are the ways of IE7...Many thanks @Nate B